# Tenserflow model for text classification doesn't predict as expected?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to train a model for sentiment analysis and it shows an accuracy of 90% when splitting the data into training and testing! But whenever I am testing it on a new phrase is has pretty much the same result(usually it's in the range 0.86 - 0.95)! 
Here is the code:

```
sentences = data['text'].values.astype('U')
y = data['label'].values

sentences_train, sentences_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(sentences, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1000)

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=5000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentences_train)

X_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(sentences_train)
X_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(sentences_test)

vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1  

maxlen = 100

X_train = pad_sequences(X_train, padding='post', maxlen=maxlen)
X_test = pad_sequences(X_test, padding='post', maxlen=maxlen)

embedding_dim = 50
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=embedding_dim,input_length=maxlen))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                    epochs=5,
                    verbose=True,
                    validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
                    batch_size=10)
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train, verbose=False)
print("Training Accuracy: {:.4f}".format(accuracy))
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=False)
print("Testing Accuracy:  {:.4f}".format(accuracy))
```

The training data is a CSV file with 3 coumns: (id, text, labels(0,1)), where 0 is positive and 1 is negative.

```
Training Accuracy: 0.9855
Testing Accuracy:  0.9013
```

Testing it on new sentences like 'This is just a text!' and 'hate preachers!' would predict the same result [0.85],[0.83].

Comment: How many training examples do you have? How did you decide to use 5k as the vocabulary size?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're victim of `overfitting`. In other words, our model would overfit to the `training data`. Although it’s often possible to achieve *high accuracy* on the training set, as in your case, what we really want is to develop models that generalize well to *testing data* (or data they haven’t seen before).

You can follow [these](https://machinelearningmastery.com/introduction-to-regularization-to-reduce-overfitting-and-improve-generalization-error/) steps in order to prevent overfitting.

Also, in order to increase the algorithm performance I suggest you to increase the number of *neurons* for `Dense` layer and set more `epochs`in order to increase the performance of the algorithm when comes to testing it to new data.

Comment: The advice in this answer does not make much sense. If overfitting is the problem, then increasing the capacity of the model or training even longer will lead to even more overfitting.

Comment: @Mathias, i know this. But i don’t think that OP has more data. Since he used very small number of epochs and small number of neurons, this can leads to slow Performance, because algorithm is not trained enough and can’t generialize to the test data

Comment: If the number of parameters would be too low, or if there would be too few epochs, this would result in low accuracy on the training data, and would be a case of _underfitting_. This is not the case.

Comment: What should be done if faced with overfitting is, for instance, 1) early stopping on validation data, 2) regularization such as dropout. Reducing number of parameters or number of epochs would also be an option, but is a "hit-and-miss" method.

Comment: @Mathias, if you’re looking in the question text you will see that training and test accuracy are pretty good, so that’s why i tend to say it’s overfitting and not underfitting

Comment: I am not claiming this is a case of underfitting - and I am claiming that your advice to increase number of parameters and/or epochs of training does not reduce overfitting, but _increases_ overfitting.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I will include your suggestion in my answer. However, i will keep also my suggestion because this increase the algorithm performance and algorithm have power to generialize more by iterating the dataset more than 5 times

Comment: My apologies, but I do not think you understand my point. You believe that the problem is overfitting. Training for even more epochs will make the problem of overfitting worse. Worse overfitting by definition means _worse performance_ - if by performance you mean accuracy on a test set. Put another way, it would lead to _less generalization_. (We can discuss this in chat if you like.)

Comment: I refers that after the overfitting problem is solved, he can use my suggestion to increase the algorithm performance.

Comment: I have increased the number of neurons to 20 and the number of epochs to 40, now the output is in the range of 0.7 - 0.9.

Comment: @Mathias what is your advice on this? I have removed the parameter of 5k as the vocabulary size as it was irrelevant! The data contains 11.000 training instances. I am new to this so I am just experimenting.